# How to Pop a Codenameone Form to show previous Form

Tags: java, swing, codenameone

So I was trying to build a custom UI among which there was **back arrow** (not the one that can be used from Form's toolbar in Codenameone) like this:

Now the issue is when I want to implement the actionListener of the **back button**, I don't seem to find the method to pop itself.

Yeah there is native support for back button with toolbar something similar to this :

```
    form.getToolbar().setBackCommand(title, evt -> menuCard.getComponentForm().showBack());
```

But i want to do something like this :

[image]

```
backButton.addActionListener {
        form.dispose()
        print("the form should dispose")
    }
```

where I want to hook the logic to **dispose / dismiss** the form to an `actionListener` of a `Button`  I can't do that as `dispose(`) on Formis **package private** .

Then I did a hack

```
package com.codename1.ui;

import com.codename1.ui.layouts.Layout

class CustomForm constructor(contentPaneLayout: Layout) : Form(contentPaneLayout) {

    public override fun dispose() {
        super.dispose()
    }
}
```

But calling `dispose()` on this new Form does not dismiss the form either.

What is the **right way to dismiss/dispose/pop** a form from its's screen to **show the previous form?**

Comment: You don't dispose() forms. That's a method of dialog. I have no idea what you're trying to do. I think you're missing the top portion of the question

Comment: Keep a reference to the previous `Form`, like in a variable `previousForm`, and then simply call `previousForm.showBack()` to show the previous `Form`. As Shai told, `dispose()` is not the right method, it's useful only with `Dialog`.

Comment: Isn't there anything similar to hide()? so that a form can disappear from top? or are there no backstack/caching of forms?

Comment: That would require that we keep in RAM all your forms which we don't. Unlike web, you're seeing state not a static web page.

Comment: That makes sense now why there isn't anything like `#pop()` in forms.